# Want to run an Action filter before the [ApiController] attribute returns an Http 400

Tags: c#, .net

I'm currently building a simple webapi using .net 6 and I've made a filter class [Filter class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WT6jY.png) to display log messages based on user validation.

I have an attribute called [ApiController] at the beginning of my [controller class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rAKGd.png) which basically returns HTTP 400 to a POST request if the validation is incorrect.

How do I ensure that that the filter class gets executed BEFORE the [ApiController] attribute.

Comment: It _WILL_ execute before the attribute. You can put in a breakpoint in both your controller and the filter and you shouldn't see the controller hit until the `next()` call occurs.

Comment: 1. Code is much preferred to images of code. 2. You can just register it as middleware like:   services.AddMvc(options => { options.Filters.Add(typeof(ExampleFilter)); });

Answer (score 0):

The two methods replace an OnActionExecuting that is executed before the request calls the code methods (the controller) and another OnResultExecuting where just before the controller result you will have a code for example :

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace MvcApplication1.ActionFilters
{
     public class LogActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute

     {
          public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
          {
               Log("OnActionExecuting", filterContext.RouteData);       
          }

          public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
          {
               Log("OnActionExecuted", filterContext.RouteData);       
          }

          public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext)
          {
               Log("OnResultExecuting", filterContext.RouteData);       
          }

          public override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext)
          {
               Log("OnResultExecuted", filterContext.RouteData);       
          }


          private void Log(string methodName, RouteData routeData)
          {
               var controllerName = routeData.Values["controller"];
               var actionName = routeData.Values["action"];
               var message = String.Format("{0} controller:{1} action:{2}", methodName, controllerName, actionName);
               Debug.WriteLine(message, "Action Filter Log");
          }

     }
}
```

if you want you can take a look at the Microsoft website too https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/understanding-action-filters-cs

you can also understand a little better the possibilities you have within .net by analyzing the flow of a request to .net it is like this

[image]

so you can analyze what could help you if the filter doesn't help you...

but if you need your response to be handled individually, I can advise you to create a method helper where you would put the response logic and could handle your responses before the action ends, but this use of filter as an interruption of an action's flow is not it is possible in .net